# Excel number and box issues

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file full of adresses which I need to import in our system.
the housenumber column is formatted like this:
Normal house numbers just show the number but house numbers with a certain boxnumber are shown like this: 25 B12
I need to get the boxnumbers (if they exist) in another column

I managed to do this with these functions

```
  Function GetBus(Text As String, ByRef NumberCell As Range) As String
        Dim LastWord As String
        LastWord = ReturnLastWord(Text)

        If Left(LastWord, 1) = "B" Then

            GetBus = Right(LastWord, Len(LastWord) - 1)


        Else
            GetBus = ""
        End If

    End Function



    Function ReturnLastWord(Text As String) As String
        Dim LastWord As String
        LastWord = StrReverse(Text)
        LastWord = Left(LastWord, InStr(1, LastWord, " ", vbTextCompare))
        ReturnLastWord = StrReverse(Trim(LastWord))
    End Function
```

So creating the new column with the box values is working. What is not working is deleting the box part in the number column (fe: if number value is 25 B1 the B1 part should be removed)

Any Ideas of how to do this or is this not possible in excel?

Comment: I wrote a similar code for someone in the past. Let me quickly search that for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something which I wrote couple of years ago so I am not sure if there are bugs in it but a quick test seems to portray that it is working correctly. You might have to change it to make it exactly work in your situation.

**Code**:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitAddress()
    Dim MyAr() As String, tempStr As String, strUnique As String
    Dim lRow As Long, i As Long, j As Long, lRow2 As Long
    Dim cell As Range

    strUnique = "SiddR" & Format(Now, "ddmmyyhhmmss")

    With ActiveSheet
        .Columns("A:A").Replace What:=" ", Replacement:=strUnique, LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        .Columns("C").NumberFormat = "@"
        .Columns("D").NumberFormat = "@"

        For i = 2 To lRow
            MyAr = Split(.Range("A" & i).Value, strUnique)

            tempStr = ""

            For j = LBound(MyAr) To (UBound(MyAr) - 1)
                If tempStr = "" Then
                    tempStr = MyAr(j)
                Else
                    tempStr = tempStr & " " & MyAr(j)
                End If
            Next j

            .Range("B" & i).Value = tempStr
            .Range("C" & i).Value = MyAr(UBound(MyAr))
        Next i

        For i = 2 To lRow
            If Not IsNumeric(.Range("C" & i).Value) Then
                tempStr = ""
                For j = 1 To Len(.Range("C" & i).Value)
                    If IsNumeric(Mid(.Range("C" & i).Value, j, 1)) Then
                        If tempStr = "" Then
                            tempStr = Mid(.Range("C" & i).Value, j, 1)
                        Else
                            tempStr = tempStr & Mid(.Range("C" & i).Value, j, 1)
                        End If
                    Else
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next
                .Range("D" & i).Value = Mid(.Range("C" & i).Value, j)
                .Range("C" & i).Value = tempStr

                If Len(Trim(tempStr)) = 0 Then
                    MyAr = Split(.Range("A" & i).Value, strUnique)

                    .Range("C" & i).Value = MyAr(UBound(MyAr) - 1)
                End If
            End If

        Next

        .Columns("A:A").Replace What:=strUnique, Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False

        .Columns("D:D").Replace What:="-", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
        ReplaceFormat:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

**Screenshot**:

[image]

**Screenshot**:

With your test data

[image]

**EDIT**: Now when I look at this code again, I see that it can be optimized much much further :)